# No funciona Timestampdiff en Clausula Where

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, timestamp

Estoy haciendo una consulta a la BBDD y quiero que me muestre sólo los registros en los que la diferencia entre la hora de la consulta `(NOW())` y la hora de la variable datetime sea menor que 60 minutos ... (que muestre todo lo que esté a mas de una hora de la hora actual)
Mirando el manual he llegado a esta consulta ... pero no me lo está filtrando:

Script PHP:

```
$consulta = "SELECT tipo,nombre,descripcion,formatoFecha FROM ".$tabla." WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,formatoFecha,NOW()) >60  ORDER BY TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,formatoFecha,NOW()) DESC";
$resultado= mysqli_query($link,$consulta);
```

echo de la consulta:

```
SELECT tipo,nombre,descripcion,formatoFecha FROM servicio WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,formatoFecha,NOW()) <60  ORDER BY TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,formatoFecha,NOW()) DESC;
```

El valor de todos los campos formatoFecha (variable datetime) es mayor que la fecha actual salvo en uno, cuyo valor es 2017-02-24 04:19:00 valor que es 60 minutos menor que la hora en que escribo la pregunta 2017-02-24 03:44:00

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

PD: he probado <60 y >60

Completo el post:

```
putenv('TZ=Europe/Madrid'); //hora de españa
```

y he añadido este echo para depurar:

```
echo $diferencia = TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,'2017-02-24 03:19:00',NOW());
```

cuyo resultado es:

```
Fatal error</b>:  Call to undefined function TIMESTAMPDIFF()
```

tambien este echo:

```
echo $hora = NOW();
```

con este resultado:

```
Fatal error</b>:  Call to undefined function NOW()
```

creo que no está la función en el hosting que utilizo, que es hostinger por si acaso

Comment: *y la hora de la variable datetime sea __menor__ que 60 minutos*: Creo que simplemente te equivocastes de operador. Usa `< 60` en vez de  `> 60`

Comment: Gracias @ sstan pero tampoco funciona, edito el post

Comment: la hora del servidor que hora te da, ose si obtienes el Now si es acorde a tu sistema horario ?.

Comment: ¿Puedes dar ejemplos de fechas en tu tabla, y del resultado esperado en cada caso, cuestión de estar seguro que entendemos lo que buscas?

Comment: puede ser que el hosting no tenga las funciones NOW() y TIMESTAMPDIFF()?

Comment: Wow yo esto igual FATAL ERROR si saben digan por favor

Comment: @sstan quiero que liste lo que falta mas de una hora para empezar, es decir, si son 60 o mas minutos o lista, si son 59 o menos no

Comment: debes de ejecutar eso como una consulta sql en MySql, creo que estas ejecutando estas sentencias en php

Comment: andrezi si, tienes razon, he copiado el echo de la consulta, lo pongo en el post, perdón

Comment: Coloca la siguiente linea de codigo despues de la llamada a la funcion `mysqli_query`

`printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($link));`
y dinos si te muestra algun error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yo corregiría 2 detalles:

1. Cambiar el operador `>` a `<`. Si no, estás haciendo lo opuesto de lo que pides.
2. Usar la función `ABS` para no caer en la trampa de obtener números negativos cuando `formatoFecha` tienes una fecha mayor a `NOW()`.

Resultado:

```
WHERE ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,formatoFecha,NOW())) < 60
```

Comment: gracias @sstan he puesto ABS y funciona, ya filtra. El >60 lo he dejado proque quiero que muestren los que esten a mas de 60 minutos de la hora actual, es decir los que queden mas de una hora para que comiencen